# Checking DLMF equation- Verify my checking/error?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

In [DLMF 16.4.11: $_3F_2$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.4#E11)
$${{}_{3}F_{2}}\left({a,b,c\atop d,e};1\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(e\right)\Gamma%
\left(d+e-a-b-c\right)}{\Gamma\left(e-a\right)\Gamma\left(d+e-b-c\right)}{{}_{%
3}F_{2}}\left({a,d-b,d-c\atop d,d+e-b-c};1\right)$$

For values $a=b=c,d=2 a,e=a+1,$
I don't get agreement for an individual term; say $a=5,k=3$  where $k$ is the usual indexing term for term order.
I do get agreement when $d=a+1,e=2 a$ ; i.e. $d$ and $e$, are swapped.
I thought I would check on a more public forum (here) before submitting a request to NIST/DLMF.  I suppose that there might be a global correction factor I am missing; i.e. corrections that apply later; but given the nature of the Generalized Hypergeometric function I doubt it.  DLMF does say, "A detailed treatment of analytic continuation in (16.4.11) and asymptotic approximations as the variables  approach infinity is given by Aomoto (1987)."
I don't have access to that.  But analytic continuation would imply an overlap between domains with restrictive ranges? I am not skilled with analytic continuation though.
This arose from analyzing: [Generalized hypergeometric function at unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2502486).
I have maxima code but I thought an outside review would be more objective; and probably neater.

Comment: DMLF formula is correct.

Comment: The formula does not claim that the series expansions on each side will agree term-by-term. It claims that the value of each side agrees. You can have two different expansions for the same thing.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  -- can you give an accessible reference?  I do have several references, but can't remember/find this relationship.  I can't afford Aomoto until I can find it used.  I believe you, but I would like to see the proof and reasoning; so I don't ask a dumb question again.

Comment: @rrogers.Gary gave the right explanation

Answer (score 1):

I have found two references proving the statement.  One using algebra, the other Calculus.  Both are understandable at undergraduate level; I think.
1)Algebraic: [Special Functions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521789885) Section 3.3 Corollary 3.3.5, but the harder, core, part is Theorem 3.3.3; Unfortunately, not available online.  Not too bad in price, though; $28 USD used.  Theorem 3.3.3 uses two specialized techniques/properties; refactoring (to misuse a software term) of Pochhammer convolutions, and a limit of Pochhammer expressions using the ratio of Gamma functions.  One technique I have used as a "trick" and the other new to me.
The difference between a trick and technique is whether you can reuse it.
2)Calculus: [A NEW PROOF OF THE FUNDAMENTAL TWO-TERM
TRANSFORMATION FOR THE SERIES 3F2(1) DUE TO THOMAE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06453.pdf).  I explored this line, but took a "wrong turn" and didn't exploit the technique as I could have.
If somebody wants, I will reconstruct [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521789885) along my own eccentric lines; but adhering to the book.  They do slip an assumption/restriction in the middle that seems out of place.
Be aware that my retelling will be fairly long.
Looking at the references, this relationship goes back to 1836 :)  So there are certainly alternate proofs.